# Why is obj.getBoundingRect() "not a function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, fabricjs

I am currently running this code on NodeJS, using the `fabric`npm package.

```
var obj
for (var i=0, max=canvas.toObject().length; i < max; i++) {
    obj = canvas.toObjects[i]
    console.log(obj.getBoundingRect())
}
```

However this crashes the program and returns:

`obj.getBoundingRect is not a function`

I have been searching around for a replacement of getting data on the bounding box of an object in NodeJS, but so far to no avail ...

Comment: Use `getBoundingClientRect()`. The error is telling you that `getBoundingRect()` is not a function because it’s not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't `obj.getBoundingRect()`, it's how your for loop is constructed.

Here's the correct syntax:

```
var allObjects = canvas.getObjects(),
    obj;
for (var i=0, max=allObjects.length; i < max; i++) {
    obj = allObjects[i];
    console.log(obj.getBoundingRect())
}
```